# How to add setOnclick in Base adapter for Listview

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I want to add a call button in list view. I have tried adding the button in the list row file and cannot add Onclick on a Java file.  There are more errors happening. Are there any other methods without button? Anyone please help me. 
 Thank you.

**Here is the Adapter code**

```
class adapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater Inflater;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return place.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Inflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=Inflater.inflate(R.layout.blood_lst,null);
           Viewholder holder=new adapter.Viewholder();

            holder.pl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bld_name);
            holder.pl.setText(place.get(position));

            holder.in=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bld_nm);
            holder.in.setText(incharge.get(position));

            holder.em=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bld_em);
            holder.em.setText(email.get(position));

            holder.ph=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bld_phn);
            holder.ph.setText(phone.get(position));

            holder.ph=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bld_grp);
            holder.ph.setText(Bld.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }
        class Viewholder{
            TextView pl;
            TextView in;
            TextView em;
            TextView ph;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a button in the listview? Or clicking the listview item itself?

Comment: Any method which is easy, i want to call the no which is showed on textview. @Derek

Comment: Check the answers to see if any worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `onClick` to the `convertView` like so:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: It is working! Thank you.. But the intent adds extra no in front of original phone no.

Comment: `convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(blood.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a button in that list view you need to add it in your item xml file like this :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_affiche_reu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        android:background="@drawable/buttonstylenormal_user"

        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Détail"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

And then in your class adapter you add this line in getView method

```
Button bt = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_affiche_reu);

            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //here you add your action 
                }
            });
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instaed of writing `onClickListener()` , you write `onItemClickListener()` for your ListView. for exemple:



     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,

 long viewId = view.getId();
 if (viewId == R.id.button1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (viewId == R.id.button2) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ListView clicked" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 


          }
    });
```